# keras custom loss number of classification errors

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I'm using keras with the tensorflow backend and trying to write a custom loss function which simply counts the number of incorrect classification predictions.  Here is my attempt:

```
def error_count_loss(yTrue, yPred):
    """Sum and return the number of incorrect predictions.

    Parameters
    ----------
    yTrue : One-hot encoded truth
    yPred : Softmax encoded prediction
    """
    yTrue_argmax = K.argmax(yTrue, axis=1)
    yPred_argmax = K.argmax(yPred, axis=1)
    incorrect_bool = K.not_equal(yTrue_argmax, yPred_argmax)
    incorrect_float = K.cast(incorrect_bool, 'float32')
    return K.sum(incorrect_float)
```

This code fails because argmax is not differentiable.  Is there a differentiable way to count incorrect predictions?

Answer (score 1):

You can try to write something close to that using other functions, which have gradients, for example:

```
def error_count_loss(yTrue, yPred):
    return K.sum(K.abs(K.sign(yTrue) - K.sign(yFalse)))
```

But it's not the best loss function for training. Try looking at [categorical_crossentropy](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/backend/categorical_crossentropy).

Comment: Thank you for the ideas and taking the time to reply.  I had previously tried categorical crossentropy, and it does work well.  However, I noticed that sometimes the models with the best cross entropy loss did not always have the fewest number of incorrect predictions (using argmax).